# correlation co-efficient meta analysis

Tags: correlation, meta-analysis, effect-size

I am conducting a correlation co-efficient meta analysis. I understand that this involves collection of effect sizes from various data presented in numerous studies. I am wondering What other data would be relevant to collect from the studies and should I be conducting any other analyses to ensure that the overall effect sizes I calculate are valid and reliable?

Comment: You may find the PRISMA guidelines http://prisma-statement.org/ helpful.